# Out of memory error for displaying facebook native ads in Android list view at multiple position

Tags: android, facebook, listview, native, ads

Facebook native ads in Android listview giving out of memory error and crashes. Initially it is able to show multiple ads at different positions in listview, but When we scroll listview it gives memory out of error. Generally it happens when we scroll list very fast and multiple times.

Comment: and with recyclerview? listview tends to store more data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue...It was due to memory leakage...List view itself manages multiple views. I was trying to manage myself.